# Reuse a captured group outside of the regex string

Tags: regex, placeholder

I'm reading from a text file that has many lines containing placeholders like this: "{name_of_placeholder}". There is another file that's like a map - the keys are the names of each placeholder and there's a value for each one. I would like to use regex to find every placeholder in the first file and replace {name_of_placeholder} with the corresponding value from the second file.

The first thing that came to my mind is to capture the group between "{}", but how to use it outside of the string? If that's not possible maybe someone can think of another way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) what language are you using ? 2) What is the exact format in 2nd file 3) give some proper input line from file 1 and file 2

Comment: 1) I'd like this replacement of placeholders to be done by a powershell script. 2) The second file is an XML, containing base64 encoded strings. 3) Here's from the first file: get { return "{ApplicationTitle}"; }

And from second: <Value>cmFuZG9taW5wdXRsaW5l</Value>

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't defined the language, but whatever the language is, you can try the following approach:

```js
var dict={}
const regex1 = /(.*)=(.*)/gm;

// let str1 be the second file (dictionary)
const str1 = `abc1=1
abc2=2
abc3=3
abc4=4
abc5=5
abc6=6
abc7=7
abc8=8
abc9=9
abc10=10
abc11=11
abc12=12`;
let m1;

while ((m1 = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null) {
    if (m1.index === regex1.lastIndex) {
        regex1.lastIndex++;
    }
  dict[m1[1]]=m1[2];
}
//console.log(dict);



const regex = /\{(.*?)\}/gm;
// let str be the first file where you want the replace operation on {key...} 
var str = `adfas{abc1} asfasdf
asdf {abc3} asdfasdf
asdfas {abc5} asdfasdf
asdfas{abc7} asdfasdfadf
piq asdfj asdf
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
      str=str.replace("\{"+m[1]+"\}",dict[m[1]]);
    
}
console.log(str);
```